# Javascript: setting a var from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables

I have an array of months like this:

```
var months = ["jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "may", "jun", "jul", "aug", "sep", "oct", "nov", "dec"];
```

What i am trying to do is make the name of the month a variable and set an object to it like so:

```
for(i=0;i<11;i++){
months[i] = $(".bitem:eq("+i+")");
}
```

But that just replaces `months[i]` (`if i=0` for example it would replace "jan" with the object). What i want to do is use the string that `months[i]` is equal to for the variable name. I tried using `.toString()` like this:

```
for(i=0;i<11;i++){
months[i].toString() = $(".bitem:eq("+i+")");
}
```

but I get the error:

```
Error: ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side
```

Comment: Are you trying to set the text of `.bitem` elements to corresponding months?

Comment: Do you want to generate `var jan = ...` dynamically?

Comment: My guess is you a) misuse classnames when you want IDs and b) want to add a .text() to your code and c) need to remove the toString from the left side of the equals like `months[i] = $(".bitem:eq("+i+")").text();`

Comment: What do you need it for? Almost every time someone ask how to create variables dynamically, there is a much better solution for what they really want to accomplish.

Comment: @Guffa Yes, the better solution was provided below.

Comment: Note: you need `i<months.length` or `i<12` or `i<=11` (with your existing `i<11` you'll skip the last month).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why exactly do you need to have variables names `jan`, `feb`, etc? From what I can tell, you can do everything you want by using a plain old object with properties:

```
var monthNames = ["jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "may", "jun", "jul", "aug", "sep", "oct", "nov", "dec"];

var months = {};
for(var i = 0; i < monthNames.length; i++) {
    months[monthNames[i]] = $(".bitem:eq("+i+")");
}

// Example usage
var januaryItem = months["jan"];
// or equivalent: months.jan;
```

Comment: This works perfect! Thank you. I tried something similar but I've been working at this so long I couldn't think clearly. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating variables, make an object that can translate the string to the index in the array:

```
var monthIndex = {
  "jan": 0, "feb": 1, "mar": 2, "apr": 3, "may": 4, "jun": 5,
  "jul": 6, "aug": 7, "sep": 8, "oct": 9, "nov": 10, "dec": 11
};
var months = $(".bitem");
```

Now given any of the month names, you can get the corresponding element from the array:

```
var m = 'aug';
var element = months[monthIndex[m]];
```

You can also use specific month names to get the index:

```
var element = months[monthIndex.aug];
```

Comment: Of course, jQuery collections are array-like, how could I forget! You can do everything with one DOM query and you even get rid of the loop. Great work! :)